# How to find the range of a function in a algebraic way

Tags: functions

I have the function 
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{(x^2-1)}+3$$
and I want to find the range of this in an algebraic way.

I have searched but I have not found anything.

How can I find that?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by saying algebraic way?

Comment: Note that $$\frac 1{(x^2-1)+3}=\frac 1{x^2+2}\le\frac 12$$

Comment: sorry but I had written it wrong first time. Now is modified

Comment: @ManolisLyviakis not using a graph

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following approach:

$$-\infty<x<\infty$$
$$0\le x^2<\infty\\
 2\le x^2-1+3<\infty\\
\frac {1}{2}\ge\frac{1}{x^2-1+3}>0$$

**Edit**

To answer the second version of your question:

$$
x\in (-\infty,\infty)\\
x^2\in [0,\infty)\\
x^2-1\in [-1,\infty)\\
\frac{1}{x^2-1}\in (-\infty,-1]\cap (0,\infty)\\
\frac{1}{x^2-1}+3\in (-\infty,2]\cap (3,\infty)
$$

Comment: sorry, but I had made a mistake, now it is correct. Could you edit your answer

Comment: I think the last line should be: (−∞,2]∩(3,∞) or am I wrong?

Comment: @ben you are right, I made a typo.